# Have Bonobos and Chimpanzees competed?

Tags: zoology

After reading de Waal's "Our Inner Ape", I'm left with the impression that chimpanzees would easily drive away or kill-off bonobos, if they were to compete for the same territory.

Have there been any instances of that in the wild? Or have their habitats always been completely separated by the Congo river?